# React native dynamic style without re render the whole component

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

Is this conditional styling below still works with react native?

```
style={[styles.base, this.state.active && styles.background]}
```

When the component is mounted, the active state is set to false.

The screen has a button to change the active state to true. Then, I would expect the background style to be displayed. But it is not the case unless the page reload.

Any thought ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be interested in using the Animated Module from react-native. By using the Animated module, you can have styles that change or animate. You could also use LayoutAnimation. You should read the [Animation Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html) and [LayoutAnimation documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html).

You can start off by using LayoutAnimation and see if that does what you need. It's quick to set up!

Here's an example:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { View, LayoutAnimation, UIManager, Platform } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
        }
    componentWillUpdate() {
        LayoutAnimation.spring() // automatimagically animates style changes
    }
    render() {
        <View style={[styles.base, this.state.active && styles.background]}>
        </View>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I need. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! Just edited your answer by adding Platform to the import from react-native.

Comment: Oh! I can't believe I missed that! :)

Comment: @sbkl I'm happy it worked for you! If it was helpful for you, would you mind upvoting as well as accepting the answer? If you used LayoutAnimation, you should try the Animated module. It takes more time to set up and is a bit more complicated, but it gives you more control and lets you animate styles.